# Multi Bancos / Cache / Camada Cliente

Tags: c#, .net, cache, nhibernate

Estamos estudando maneiras de desenvolver umas funcionalidades para um sistema, que será em C# .Net.

Gostaria de ouvi opiniões de como podemos fazer isto, se podemos usar alguns *frameworks* ou alguma outra coisa.

1. Acesso a múltiplos bancos

Precisamos que o sistema funcione em diversos bancos de dados. Por exemplo, no PHP utilizando o *framework* CodeIginiter, tu escreve as *queries* na linguagem do *framework* e ele “monta” as *queries* para o banco que tu escolher. Podemos utilizar o NHibernate para fazer isto?

2. Cache

O sistema tem que ter um cache para armazenar dados na memória e ter acesso rápido a esses dados.

3. Camada Cliente de Desenvolvimento

Precisamos que seja possível desenvolver algumas funcionalidades no sistema especificamente para um cliente. Por exemplo, ter um botão a mais em uma tela e que possa ser feito atualização e manter estas alterações.

Comment: É importante dizer que perguntas aqui do Stack Overflow não devem ser baseadas em opiniões. Darei uma opinião tentando ser o mais técnico e imparcial possível.

Comment: Você ja decidiu qual banco de dados utilizar? isso é muito importante para a agrupação de qual tecnologia utilizar.

Answer (score 2):

Posso sugerir algo relacionado a cache, que a meu ver faz toda a diferença na hora de atender altos volumes de transações/acessos concorrentes. Trata-se do framework [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), que depois de longo tempo de desenvolvimento é um sistema estável e seguro e grátis.
Há farto material de apoio, com [vídeos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AAP314) e documentação disponível.

Comment: Não conhecia. Obrigado pela sugestão. +1.

Answer (score 1):

## Podemos utilizar o NHibernate para fazer isto?

Sim, podem. [Aqui está a lista de tecnologias de bases de dados que o NHibernate trabalha](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasesSupportedByNHibernate?_sscc=t).

## O sistema tem que ter um cache para armazenar dados na memória e ter acesso rápido a esses dados.

Possivelmente estamos falando de caches de segundo nível. [Aqui há um artigo explicando como usar caches de segundo nível no NHibernate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529016/NHibernate-Second-Level-Caching-Implementation). A ideia é análoga ao Hibernate.

## Precisamos que seja possível desenvolver algumas funcionalidades no sistema especificamente para um cliente. Por exemplo, ter um botão a mais em uma tela e que possa ser feito atualização e manter estas alterações.

Sendo assim, primeiro deve-se escolher uma abordagem a seguir.

Se estamos falando da abordagem ***Multi-Tenant*** (*Multi-inquilino*, em tradução livre), temos um produto para vários clientes, e todos os clientes dividem a mesma base de dados e as mesmas funcionalidades, salvo configurações de ambiente.

Se estamos falando da abordagem ***Multi-Instance*** (*Multi-instâncias*, em tradução livre), temos um produto para cada cliente. Neste caso, é interessante separar a camada de apresentação das demais camadas.

- Para um sistema 3 Camadas, a camada de negócio (serviço) deve ser uma DLL, e a camada de repositório outra DLL (estou supondo NHibernate para afirmar isso); A camada de apresentação deve ser uma *Web Application*;
- Para um sistema MVC, a camada de apresentação (*Views*) deve ser uma *Web Application* e as demais camadas uma DLL.

Em ambos os dados, a *Web Application* deve pelo menos referenciar uma das DLLs, sendo a DLL de serviços no caso do sistema 3 camadas.